# OneDrive REST APIs: "message": "The specified item does not have content." when downloading a file

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

## the use case

I would like to download an excel sheet from OneDrive using the REST API

Documentation:

the documentation proposed to call this Endpoint : `GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content`

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

## prerequisites

1. I am correctly logged using oauth2, all other methods work such as '/me', '/me/drive/recent', '/me/drive/sharedWithMe'
2. The granted credentials on

## The error message when I call `GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}/content`

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound", 
    "innerError": {
      "client-request-id": "aaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaa", 
      "date": "2020-09-26T09:19:08", 
      "request-id": "aaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaa-aaa"
    }, 
    "message": "The specified item does not have content."
  }
}
```

## The file exists and contains data when I call `GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}`

The file exists and weight : 46.272 bytes

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('<a_username>%40hotmail.com')/drive/items/$entity", 
  "createdBy": {
    "user": {
      "displayName": "<a_name> ", 
      "id": "<a_drive_id>"
    }
  }, 
  "createdDateTime": "2020-09-27T07:29:04.893Z", 
  "eTag": "<an_eTag>", 
  "fileSystemInfo": {
    "lastAccessedDateTime": "2020-09-27T11:52:31Z"
  }, 
  "id": "<a_drive_id>!<a_sub_id>", 
  "lastModifiedBy": {
    "user": {
      "displayName": "<a_name> ", 
      "id": "<a_drive_id>"
    }
  }, 
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-09-27T18:46:25.073Z", 
  "name": "a_filename.xlsx", 
  "parentReference": {
    "driveId": "<a_drive_id>", 
    "driveType": "personal"
  }, 
  "remoteItem": {
    "file": {}, 
    "fileSystemInfo": {
      "lastAccessedDateTime": "2020-09-27T11:52:31Z"
    }, 
    "id": "<an_id>!7757", 
    "name": "a_filename.xlsx", 
    "parentReference": {
      "driveId": "<an_id>", 
      "driveType": "personal"
    }, 
    "size": 46272, 
    "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/u/<a_letter>!<a_web_url_id>"
  }, 
  "webUrl": "https://1drv.ms/u/<a_letter>!<a_web_url_id>"
}
```

## Conclusion

Is there a bug in the implementation of the API by Microsoft ?!?

What do I do wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to call, are you testing it in Graph Explorer or in Postman or any application you are using? If you can also share the request id and timestamp it can help us.

Comment: `/me/drive/items/{item-id}` supposed to give you a long URL as `@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl` . This URL downloads the file even for anonymous visitors. Do you have this url? What does it display?

Comment: I'm starting a bounty on this I have been stuck on the same issue for hours. @ShivaKeshavVarma I am using the Python quickstart with msal in a Flask context. id/timestamp: 
            "date": "2022-04-18T15:38:59",
            "request-id": "1f573177-317e-4181-8582-61450e48069d"

Comment: Try this API call and see if it works. `me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/content`

Comment: According to the api document, I think we need to make sure the target item can be downloaded and notice if we are stopped by 302 redirection.@Neil

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we need to notice that in the api document, it mentioned:

> Only driveItems with the file property can be downloaded.

So we need to make sure the target item has the propertiy `file` in the response when we called `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/item_id`

[image]

Then we need to pay attention to [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#downloading-files-in-javascript-apps), when we can call the download api successfully, it will return a 302 redirection

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your situation, but make sure you have checked-in your file if you happened to have uploaded it programmatically. OneDrive/SharePoint likes to put files into no-man's land if it has not been properly checked-in.

Documentation:

Download: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-checkout?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Checkin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-checkin?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http